# How do we create a block (reusable set of functions) in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `Keras`, actually `tensorflow.keras` to be specific and want to know if it is possible to create reusable blocks of inbuilt Keras layers. For example I would like to repeatedly use the following block at different times in my model.

```
conv1a = Conv3D(filters=32, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
bn1a = BatchNormalization()(conv1a)
relu1a = ReLU()(bn1a)
conv1b = Conv3D(filters=32, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same')(relu1a)
bn1b = BatchNormalization()(conv1b)
relu1b = ReLU()(bn1b)
```

I have read about [creating custom layers in Keras](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) but I did not find the documentation to be clear enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are some missing parentheses in your snippet. In any case, there are two different things here. One is adding new layers with the same structure at different points in the model. For that, you can simply use a Python function that takes the input and gives you the output after the new layers. The other case is reusing the same set of layers (with the same weights) at different points in the model. In that case you can make a `Model` or `Sequential` object and use it like a layer at different points. But I'm not sure that's what you actually want.

Comment: @jdehesa I have added the missing parentheses. Yes, I am referring to "adding new layers with the same structure at different points in the model." How would the said python function be used when using the `Model` (functional API)? Can you illustrate it in the form of how you can pass an input to the function and how the output of the function would used as an input to the next layer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could simply put it inside a function then use like:

```
relu1a = my_block(inputs)
relu1b = my_block(relu1a)
```

Also consider adding something such as `with K.name_scope('MyBlock'):` in the beginning of your function, so that things get wrapped in the graph as well.

So you'd have something like:

```
def my_block(inputs, block_name='MyBlock'):
  with K.name_scope(block_name):
    conv = Conv3D(filters=32, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
    bn = BatchNormalization()(conv)
    relu = ReLU()(bn)

  return relu
```

If you specify block names:

```
relu1a = my_block(inputs, 'Block1')
relu1b = my_block(relu1a, 'Block2')
```

Comment: can you illustrate the `with K.name_scope('MyBlock'):` part with an example?

Comment: there you go @JashShah

Comment: Two questions:
1. How would the `name_scope()` function look like when I am using `tf.keras`?
2. How would the layer named `relu1b` be used as an input for let's say a `Conv3D` layer?

Comment: For `name_scope`, it's TensorFlow's equivalent actually, so this will get things organized in your graph (you'll be able to see in TensorBoard). For the other question as long as the shape fits in `Conv3D`, there should be no problem. You can adjust dimensions and reshape as well to make them compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Define a method that receives your model and returns it with the added layers. Here's an example:

```
def get_modified_model(model):
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS,)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

such that the argument `model` passed to `get_model` is obtained from `keras.models.Sequential()`